# seaborn distribution plot add label for counts per histogram bin

Tags: python, label, histogram, seaborn, distribution

How can I get seaborn to add a label for the distribution plot which contains the number of elements per bin?

```
import seaborn as sns, numpy as np
sns.set(); np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.randn(100)
ax = sns.distplot(x)
```

should instead of the default distribution plot add a label for each bar:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rough solution could be:

```
import seaborn as sns, numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# add the following line if working on jupyter notebook
%matplotlib inline

sns.set()
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.randn(100)
ax = sns.distplot(x)

s = 0

for p in ax.patches:
    s+= p.get_height()

for p in ax.patches: 
    ax.text(p.get_x() + p.get_width()/2.,
            p.get_height(),
            '{}'.format(int(p.get_height()*100/s)), 
            fontsize=14,
            color='red',
            ha='center',
            va='bottom')
plt.show()
```

and you get:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not plot the image for me. It looks like the rectangles are added though.

Comment: Please, check again.

Comment: Hm I already had `%pylab inline` Jupiter, so it should have worked. Your suggestions do not result in an image for me, though seaboard will happily plot its results.

Comment: Add `%matplotlib inline` if you are working on jupyter notebook.